# Undefined variable when I try to pass array to a class which extends another one

Tags: php

My controller.php looks simular to: https://github.com/panique/mini/blob/master/application/core/controller.php

My album.php looks simular to: https://github.com/panique/mini/blob/master/application/controller/songs.php

Album extends Controller. I want to "create" client i controller.php and be able to use it in all functions in album.php

controller.php

```
class Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->openDatabaseConnection();
        $this->loadModel();
        $this->aws();
    }

    public function aws()
    {
         $client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key'    => AWS_KEY,
                'secret' => AWS_SECRET,
                )
            ));
    }
}
```

album.php

```
class Album extends Controller
{
   public $client;

   function __construct($client)
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->client = $client;
   } 

   public function index()
    {
    //access $this-client here
    }

   public function myfunction()
    {
    //access $this-client here
    }
}
```

In other words, I want to use $client in all my functions in the class album.php

Error

> Undefined variable: client in album.php

Comment: Why not simply assign your $client var to a property in Controller class and have it available in any class that extends the Controller? What you're doing here makes literally no sense.

Comment: I dont' know ;) Can you give me an example of how it would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
<?php 

class Controller
{

    public $client;
    public $dbConn;

    function __construct(DatabaseClass $dbConn)
    {
        // $this->openDatabaseConnection(); // Database connections should be passed in as a dependency via the construct, just a suggestion
        $this->dbConn = $dbConn;
        $this->loadModel(); 
        $this->aws();
    }

    public function aws()
    {
         $this->client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key'    => AWS_KEY,
                'secret' => AWS_SECRET,
                )
            ));
    }
}
```

No need to have $client here

```
class Album extends Controller
{

   function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
   } 

   public function index()
    {
    //access $this-client here
    }

   public function myfunction()
    {
    //access $this->client here
    }
}
```